# mysql decimal(10,2) extract java

Tags: java, mysql

I have my database with an decimal(10,2) value.

I need to extract it from the database and add a quantity with java, but I don't get it.

From the database query, the value is 5.50

```
System.out.println(rsMax.getLong(1));
Long cost = rsMax.getLong(1) + 2;
```

This prints 5 and cost = 7, it should print 5.50 and cost = 7.50

how should I do it?

Comment: a `long` is an integer. You need a floating point type.

Comment: which mysql version r u using?

Answer (score 1):

`Long` is an integer. You need the `BigDecimal` type.

Comment: Though a bit cumbersome to use (`.add`, `.multiply`), that is definitely the way to go.